# how to make separate list from Json response in python

Tags: python, json, list

```
{
  "total": 5,
  "start": 0,
  "limit": 10,
  "results": [
    {
      "firstName": "stage",
      "lastName": "user",
      "country": "IN",
      "state": "TN",
      "city": "Saint Thomas Mount",
      "containersSelected": [
        "CIEP",
        "CIES",
        "sthub"
      ],
      "created": "2020-07-23T03:29:49.394Z",
      "updated": "2020-07-23T03:29:59.663Z"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Automation",
      "lastName": "Testing",
      "country": "IN",
      "state": "TN",
      "city": "Saint Thomas Mount",
      "containersSelected": [
        "CIEP",
        "CIES"
      ],
      "created": "2020-07-22T03:25:00.510Z"
    },
    {
       "firstName": "Test",
      "lastName": "elite",
      "country": "IN",
      "state": "TN",
      "city": "Chennai",
      "containersSelected": [
        "iothub",
        "CIEP",
        "CIES"
      ],
      "created": "2020-03-05T06:41:07.884Z"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Amani",
      "lastName": "I",
      "country": "IN",
      "state": "TG",
      "city": "Hyderabad",
      "containersSelected": [
        "iothub",
        "CIEP",
        "CIES"
      ],
      "created": "2019-10-15T06:23:14.857Z"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Venkatesh",
      "lastName": "Chandu",
      "country": "IN",
      "state": "TG",
      "city": "Hyderabad",
      "containersSelected": [
        "iothub",
        "CIEP",
        "CIES"
      ],
      "created": "2019-09-11T09:56:02.540Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

here I used code was

```
Containerallowedlist = []
data = response.json()
for containers in data['results']:
    for list in containers['containersSelected']:
        Containerallowedlist.append(list)
```

Output I Got was : ['CIEP', 'CIES', 'sthub', 'CIEP', 'CIES', 'iothub', 'CIEP', 'CIES', 'iothub', 'CIEP', 'CIES', 'iothub', 'CIEP', 'CIES']

But I need output was :  [[‘CIEP', 'CIES', 'sthub’],[’CIEP', 'CIES', 'iothub’],[ 'CIEP', 'CIES', 'iothub’], [‘CIEP', 'CIES', 'iothub’], [‘CIEP', 'CIES’]]

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension for this `[i["containersSelected"] for i in a["results"]]`.

If using your code

```
In [21]: Containerallowedlist = []
    ...: for containers in a['results']:
    ...:         Containerallowedlist.append(containers["containersSelected"])
```

```
In [15]: a
Out[15]:
{'total': 5,
 'start': 0,
 'limit': 10,
 'results': [{'firstName': 'stage',
   'lastName': 'user',
   'country': 'IN',
   'state': 'TN',
   'city': 'Saint Thomas Mount',
   'containersSelected': ['CIEP', 'CIES', 'sthub'],
   'created': '2020-07-23T03:29:49.394Z',
   'updated': '2020-07-23T03:29:59.663Z'},
  {'firstName': 'Automation',
   'lastName': 'Testing',
   'country': 'IN',
   'state': 'TN',
   'city': 'Saint Thomas Mount',
   'containersSelected': ['CIEP', 'CIES'],
   'created': '2020-07-22T03:25:00.510Z'},
  {'firstName': 'Test',
   'lastName': 'elite',
   'country': 'IN',
   'state': 'TN',
   'city': 'Chennai',
   'containersSelected': ['iothub', 'CIEP', 'CIES'],
   'created': '2020-03-05T06:41:07.884Z'},
  {'firstName': 'Amani',
   'lastName': 'I',
   'country': 'IN',
   'state': 'TG',
   'city': 'Hyderabad',
   'containersSelected': ['iothub', 'CIEP', 'CIES'],
   'created': '2019-10-15T06:23:14.857Z'},
  {'firstName': 'Venkatesh',
   'lastName': 'Chandu',
   'country': 'IN',
   'state': 'TG',
   'city': 'Hyderabad',
   'containersSelected': ['iothub', 'CIEP', 'CIES'],
   'created': '2019-09-11T09:56:02.540Z'}]}

In [16]: [i["containersSelected"] for i in a["results"]]
Out[16]:
[['CIEP', 'CIES', 'sthub'],
 ['CIEP', 'CIES'],
 ['iothub', 'CIEP', 'CIES'],
 ['iothub', 'CIEP', 'CIES'],
 ['iothub', 'CIEP', 'CIES']]
```